# Reading url parameters in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to read URL parameters from browser and assign it to a variable. My url will be like `http://localhost:9090/ngdemo/apd.html?id=bookid-1` . I need to get bookid-1 from the url. I tried `$location.search(), $location.$$path` but I am not getting the value 'bookid-1' .

My controller code is

```
app.controller('apdController', function($scope, getTocService,$location,$routeParams) {
    var bookId = $location.search();
    var param1 = $routeParams.param1;

});
```

app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/view3/:param1', {templateUrl: 'apd.html', controller: 'apdController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

What is the change I need to make to get bookid-1 here?

Comment: Did you try `$location.search().id`?

Comment: your parameter is `id`, not `bookId` nor `param1`.  have you tried `var bookId = $routeParams.id;`?

Comment: do you have `ui-router` or `ng-router`?

Comment: @Phil. Thanks a lot..! Worked perfectly with $location.search().id..Please put it as answer. I will accept it.